# How to find the order of a dihedral group made up of two elements of order $2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I have a group $\langle x,y \rangle$ that is a dihedral group and nonabelian and $x,y$ both have order $2$. I have worked it out that the group $ \langle xy,y \rangle$ is equivalent to $\langle x,y \rangle$ such that the order of $xy$ is $n$. How would I go about finding $n$ such that the order of the group is $2n$?

Comment: The order is $2|xy|$.  For a reference see:  Borovik and Borovik, _Mirrors and Reflections, The Geometry of Finite Reflection Groups_, Chapter $7$, Universitext, Springer, $2010$.

Comment: It turns out that this can be done for any $n$.  That the group is nonabelian implies $n\ge3$.